# Internet Explorer content display issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

IE version: 11.309.16299.0

When web page is loaded some of the content goes invisible:

[Image with no content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Snxtt.png)

But content becomes visible when i hold left click and drag mouse to select the area:

[image]

The chart i am using is Google Chart.

```js
google.charts.load("current", {
    packages: ["corechart"]
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var store = 12;
    var web = 88;
    var disabledColor = "#417505";
    if (store == 0 && web == 0) {
        store = 100;
        disabledColor = "#9B9B9B";
    }
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['', ''],
        ['Store', store],
        ['Web', web],
    ]);

    var options = {
        height: 130,
        width: 130,
        pieHole: 0.4,
        legend: 'none',
        colors: [disabledColor, '#9B9B9B'],
        chartArea: {
            left: 20,
            top: 15,
            width: "80%",
            height: "80%"
        },
        'tooltip': {
            trigger: 'none'
        },
        enableInteractivity: false,
        pieSliceBorderColor: "transparent",
        pieSliceText: "none",
        animation: {
            duration: 1000,
            easing: 'out'
        },
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function() {
        // do stuff when the chart is done drawing

    });
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="donutchart" style="position: relative; left: 14px;">
                                </div>
```

Comment: Looks like it is taking the font color as white. Apply the `color` for the body as block like `body{color:#000;}`.

Comment: If its taking font as white, the font over the green and red bars will still be visible initially. Can you post your HTML and CSS?

Comment: If the issue was with font color the other fonts should also not be visible.

Comment: And also the green and red bar is purely html and css having fixed height and width so it has nothing to do with font color.

Comment: I supposed so. Can you add the full code? (Html, css, js)

Comment: Your snippet is only writing the donut.